# Access WISP LAN Network From Access Point Wifi Network

Tags: networking, router, lan, ipv4

I'm using TP-LINK TL-WR840N (master router) as a Access Point and TL-MR3020(slave router) as a WISP, from slave router LAN port I have connected a device. The WIFI IP is in 0 series and the LAN series is 1, how I can access WISP device LAN port(1 series) device from Master Router(0 Series).

So my question is

**How to ping different IP Series in same Network (One is Router LAN Network and Other is Router Wifi Network)?**

Comment: Hi, could you add the question itself to the question body? That makes it a lot easier to understand what you really are looking for.

Comment: hi @norway-yv thanks for suggestion, i have made changes, is it ok

Comment: Great, now you avoid the strictest people downvoting for no reasonable reason @Codexxx